# Direct solution to maximum likelihood computation problem using the derivative of multivariate Gaussian w.r.t. covariance matrix

Tags: partial-derivative, inverse, trace, maximum-likelihood

For an application, I need to compute the maximum loglikelihood of data coming from a $d$-dimensional multivariate Gaussian random variable:
$$
\textbf{x} \sim \mathcal{N}(\boldsymbol{\mu}, \Sigma)
$$
where the covariance matrix $\Sigma$ is a function two scalars $\sigma, \gamma$ such that $\Sigma = \sigma V + \gamma I$ and $V$ is symmetric and independent of both $\gamma$ and $\sigma$.

I have already computed the maximum likelihood using R `optim` function. However, I was wondering if I could directly compute the optimal $\sigma$ and $\gamma$ using some closed-form expression.

For this, I tried to follow the steps given in the answer provided by @greg for a  similar question ([Derivation of derivative of multivariate Gaussian w.r.t. covariance matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2867022/derivation-of-derivative-of-multivariate-gaussian-w-r-t-covariance-matrix)). However I am stuck at the step which involves expanding $\Sigma^{-1} = (\sigma V + \gamma I)^{-1}$.

My derivations are as follows. Using the same notations in the answer for $\Sigma=S$, $Z = X-\mu1$, $A : B = \text{tr}(A^TB)$,

\begin{align}
dL &= (S^{-1} - S^{-1} Z Z^T S^{-1}) : dS \\
&= (S^{-1} - S^{-1} Z Z^T S^{-1}) : (d\sigma V + \sigma dV + d\gamma I) 
\end{align}

Setting $dV=0$ and $d\gamma=0$ to get partial derivative w.r.t $\sigma$,
\begin{align}
dL &= (S^{-1} - S^{-1} Z Z^T S^{-1}) : (d\sigma V) \\
& = d\sigma\, \text{tr}((S^{-1} - S^{-1}Z Z^T S^{-1})^TV) 
\end{align}

That implies,
\begin{align}
\frac{dL}{d\sigma} &=  \text{tr}((S^{-1} - S^{-1}Z Z^T S^{-1})^TV) \\
& = \text{tr}((\sigma V + \gamma I)^{-1} - (\sigma V + \gamma I)^{-1} Z Z^T (\sigma V + \gamma I)^{-1})^T V)
\end{align}

Similarly, by setting $dV=0$ and $d\sigma=0$, we get partial derivative w.r.t $\gamma$,
\begin{align}
\frac{dL}{d\gamma} &=  \text{tr}(\sigma V + \gamma I)^{-1} - (\sigma V + \gamma I)^{-1} Z Z^T (\sigma V + \gamma I)^{-1})
\end{align}

Is there a way to solve $\frac{dL}{d\sigma}=0$ and $\frac{dL}{d\gamma}=0$ to get closed-form solution for $\gamma$ and $\sigma$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be better off solving the gradient for $S$, i.e.
$$\eqalign{
\frac{\partial L}{\partial S} &= \big(S^{-1} - S^{-1}ZZ^TS^{-1}\big) \;=\; 0 \cr
S^{-1} &= S^{-1}ZZ^TS^{-1} \cr
S &= ZZ^T \cr
}$$
Then find the values of $(\sigma,\gamma)$ which yield (in a least-squares sense) this matrix.
$$\eqalign{
\min_{\sigma,\gamma} \; \Big\|\,\sigma V + \gamma I - ZZ^T\Big\|^2_F \cr
}$$
Start with an easy problem whose solution is well known.
$$\eqalign{
\min_\alpha \|\alpha A-C\|^2_F \implies \alpha = \frac{A:C}{A:A} \cr
}$$
Setting $\,\alpha A=\sigma V$ and $C=(ZZ^T-\gamma I),\,$ and then

setting $\,\alpha A=\gamma I\,$ and $C=(ZZ^T-\sigma V)\,$ yields the scalars. 
$$\eqalign{
\sigma = \frac{V:(ZZ^T-\gamma I)}{V:V},\quad 
\gamma = \frac{I:(ZZ^T-\sigma V)}{I:I} \cr
}$$
Plug the $\gamma$-expression into the $\sigma$-expression (and vice versa) to obtain
$$\eqalign{
\sigma &= \frac{(I:I)(V:ZZ^T) - (V:I)(I:ZZ^T)}{(I:I)(V:V) - (V:I)(I:V)},\quad
\gamma &= \frac{(V:V)(I:ZZ^T) - (I:V)(V:ZZ^T)}{(V:V)(I:I) - (I:V)(V:I)} \cr
}$$
Note that the formulas are conjugate to one other, under the interchange of $\,I\Longleftrightarrow V$.

Comment: Thank you so much @greg. I will implement this direct solution in my application by replacing the solution via `optim` and let you know how it goes.

Comment: For my application, $\mu = W\theta$ for appropriate dimensions. Do you think the approach would still work, i.e., taking the least squared approximation of $S \approx ZZ^T$? I am worried that now the optimal $\theta$ is a function of $S$, unlike the previous question where $\mu$ is the sample mean and independent of $S$.

Comment: Just to confirm, I am trying to fit data $\textbf{x} \sim \mathcal{N}(\boldsymbol{\mu}, \Sigma)$
where the covariance matrix $\Sigma$ is a function of two scalar variables $\sigma, \gamma$ such that $\Sigma = \sigma V + \gamma I$ and $\color{red}{\mu = W\theta}$ where $\theta$ is a vector variable and $W$ is a matrix of appropriate dimension. Both $V,W$ are independent of $\gamma,\sigma,\theta$ and $V$ is symmetric.

Comment: Finding the optimal $\theta$ vector will be much harder. I doubt there's a closed form solution for the entire set of parameters: $\,(\gamma, \sigma, \theta)$.

Comment: Yes. By keeping one of $\sigma$ or $\gamma$ variable I can get closed form of the other and $\theta$. But not all three. I expressed $\gamma$ as $\gamma/\sigma$ and then derived $\theta$ as generalized least squared estimator.